# How to refresh LoaderManager

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, android-loadermanager

I read many posts and guides but I'm still facing many problems when using `LoaderManager` to get data from an `SQLite` database.

I've been struggling with it for more than one week and I edited my code many times, following many different examples, but the problem is still there.

First of all, I have to say that my `AsyncTaskLoader` returns a List of objects created by me, so I can't rely on `CursorLoader` methods to "refresh" the query.

This is my `AsyncTaskLoader` from which I get a List of MyContact

```
public class MyLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<MyContact>>{
    private List<MyContact> myContacts;   
    private Bundle bundle;   

    public MyLoader(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
        super(context);
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

    public List<MyContact> loadInBackground(){
        myContacts = //here I build my List of  MyContact with data taken from a DB 
        return myContacts;
    }    
}
```

This is my activity where I implement LoaderManager methods:

```
public class ContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<MyContact>>{

     private LoaderManager loaderManager;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         loaderManager = getLoaderManager();    
         loaderManager.initLoader(1, null, this);    
     }

    ....
    @Override
    public Loader<List<MyContact>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
         return new MyLoader(this, bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<MyContact>> loader, List<MyContact> myContacts) {
          Here I fill a RecyclerView with myContacts
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<MyContact>> loader) {
    }
}
```

My problem is that after the database is updated, I should get an update list of MyContacts, by "refreshing" the loaderManager. I'm not going to show you all the differents way I tried to achieve my goal.

I tried many ways following examples on SO and on other sites, I even implemented a `BroadcastReceiver`, but I couldn't make it work, and I'm not able to understand my error since I don't get any "java" error.

Answer (score 2):

Try following on refresh. It reset and restart loader for respective loader Id.     Though I have use it for cursor , it should work for custom object too.

```
loaderManager.restartLoader(loaderId, null, context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this following line of code right after making an update to the SQLite database:

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```